# Asymptotic behaviour of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

We fix $\alpha >0$, and we look for the asymptotic behaviour when $n \to +\infty$ of
$$u_n=1^{\alpha n}+2^{\alpha n}+\cdots+n^{\alpha n}.$$
Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand what "the equivalent in $+\infty$" means. What is the context? Can you explain more?

Comment: For example we know that $\log(1+\frac{1}{n})$ is equivalent to $ \frac{1}{n}$ in $+\infty$

Comment: I think sbr is looking for something similar to $n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt {2\pi n}$ (kind of equivalence).

Answer (score 1):

Put $a_n=n^{-n\alpha}u_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(1-k/n)^{n\alpha}$. We'll show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1+e^{-\alpha}+e^{-2\alpha}+\dotsb=1/(1-e^{-\alpha})$$

Since $(1-k/n)^n\le e^{-k}$ (see footnote), we have
$$a_n\le\sum_{k=0}^ne^{-k\alpha}$$
Let $n\to\infty$, we obtain
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\le1+e^{-\alpha}+e^{-2\alpha}+\dotsb$$
Now fix $m$ and consider $n\ge m$, we have
$$a_n\ge\sum_{k=0}^m\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{n\alpha}$$
Let $n\to\infty$, we obtain
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\ge1+e^{-\alpha}+e^{-2\alpha}+\dotsb$$
Proved.

Footnote: Fix $k$, consider $x_n=(1-k/n)^n$, we have:

1. $x_1\le x_2\le\dotsb$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=e^{-k}$

I think you can prove it alone.